# Processing content of textarea once button is clicked

Tags: fable-f#

While learning Fable and Elmish I thought it is a good exercise to handle the input from a user and do something with it. So I tried to create a textarea and a button and if that button is pressed the input from the textarea should be submitted. However, I'm really puzzled with how to get the value from the textarea. Here is my starter:

```ml
type Model = string
type Msg = UserInput of string

let init () : Model = ""

let update (msg: Msg) (_: Model) =
    let UserInput x = msg
    x

let view (model: Model) dispatch =
    div [] [ textarea [] []
             button [] [str "submit"]
             div [] [str model] ]
```

Ideally if the user enters some text into the textarea and presses the submit button I would like to echo the users input in the div at the bottom. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using Elmish. Note that this is an extra layer on top of the React bindings and it is very opinionated! You also can write React components directly or use an alternative system like [Feliz](https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/Feliz), which looks more like modern TypeScript with hooks.

On to your question. You need to do two things:

1. *dispatch* a message every time the user changes the `textarea` value
2. Set the value of the `textarea` based on the model

```ml
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.React

type Model = string
type Msg = UserInput of string

let init () : Model = ""

let update (msg: Msg) (_: Model) =
    let (UserInput x) = msg
    x

let view (model: Model) dispatch =
    div 
      [] 
      [ 
        textarea 
          [
            Props.Value model
            Props.OnChange 
              (fun e -> e.target?value |> UserInput |> dispatch)
          ] 
          []
        button [] [str "submit"]
        div [] [str model] 
      ]
```